# MongoDB/Spring: Subscribing to collection changes

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, events, changestream

I'm working with a Spring Boot app. I'm trying to implement callback-based event notification for collection modifications in a MongoDB. I'm running out of ideas, as I have tried the following:

- Classic Polling - Redundant, as the existing implementation is a REST endpoint that's polled by the UI, where it queries data.
- Tailable Cursors - Requires a collection to be capped, which is likely a limitation that won't suffice for a database with a very high storage forecast.
- Change Streams - I got a runtime exception stating that the storage engine doesn't support 'Majority Read Concern'. 
  `collection.watch(asList(Aggregates.match(Filters.in("operationType", asList("insert", "update"))))).forEach(printBlock);`

I'm not authorizated to view the engine configuration, but I'm assuming if the DBA can't change the storage engine to wiredTiger, than I can't use change streams. Is this correct? Are there other solutions? How about spring's mongodb-reactive API? I was under the impression the API still depends on tailable cursors or change streams.